# ParseQueryAdapter Cannot reslove symbol

Tags: java, android, parse-android-sdk

I am using Parse Library:

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
```

I am getting error with ParseQueryAdapter cannot resolve symbol.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is part of [parse ui](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android) now. Adding

```
compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
```

To your build.gradle and you should be able to import it. You can read more in the [changelogs](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/releases/tag/1.10.0) of parse